# nocite{*} and unsrt

Tags: bibliographies

I want to have my bibliography with the same exact order as it is on my `.bib` file, even if I don't cite all the entries. I am using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and `\nocite{*}`:

```
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
% ... and so on
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have something like "... as shown on a large number of studies ([2]-[6])." But I end up with "... studies ([2]-[3])." and all the uncited entries ([3], [4] and [5]) are shown at the end of the bibliography.

Is there any way to have all the cited and no cited entries with the same order as the bib file?

Any help would be great!

Edit: It turned out that having `\nocite{*}` BEFORE all the `\include{chapters}` solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code fragment isn't that clear but you want `\nocite{*}` to be first not last, before all `\cite` commands.