# sequence of bibliography items getting ramdomly altered

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to write bibliography using biblitex and have declared 15 items. eg.:

```
@Article{1,
  title={article 1},
  author={name},
  booktitle={}  
}

@Article{2,
  title={article 2},
  author={name},
  booktitle={}  
}

@Article{3,
  title={article 3},
  author={name},
  booktitle={}  
}
```

normally its expected output of this to be

> [1] article 1
>    [2] article 2
>    [3] article 3

but I'm getting random output as:

> [1] article 3
>    [2] article 1
>    [3] article 2

Is there any way to get the list in ordered manner..

EDIT: my main tex file is as: (report.tex)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\textwidth 6.5in
\textheight 9.5in
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{p1.tex}
\bibliography{bibli.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  are you specifying a `\bibliographystyle`, and if so, what is it?  we really need more information to diagnose the problem. please post a full (small) example that demonstrates the problem, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  that will enable the people here to test and experiment for themselves.

Comment: the `plain` bibliography style, which you're using, will sort the bibliography entries by author and then by year.  a method to achieve the order you want is addressed in [`nocite{*}` and `unsrt`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231203/579).

Comment: It's unrelated, but you should not include the extension in the `\bibliography` command: `\bibliography{bibli}`. With your code, only MiKTeX based systems will be able to find the file.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{unsrt} works perfect